# Handle errors using route resolver

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm using a simple route resolver to load data before user access a page:

```
resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
      return this.summaryService.getAllAnalytics();
  }
```

How I can handle the error that may occur when an API call fails (bad connection or any other reason), stop the user from routing to the requested page, and show an error instead?

Currently, when there is a problem with my API I get the following error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]
```

and the page remains the same. I couldn't how I can handle the error I get.

Comment: Have you tried implementing `CanActivate` on your route guard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your service returns a Promise then you can use [Promise.prototype.catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) method, and if it returns an Observable then use [Rx.Observable.catch](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/catch.html)

Inside catch you can log errors or/and redirect to error page or/and redirect somewhere else...

In case of Observable it would look something like this:

```ts
import { of } from "rxjs/observable/of";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
...
resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
      return this.summaryService.getAllAnalytics()
          .catch(err => {
              console.error(err);
              return of();
          });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, It seems like I had to `import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';`.

Comment: Yes. That's a right way if you don't wand to include all operators into your bundle.

Comment: @TheUnreal please mark my answer as a correct if it helped you so other people can also stick with it faster.